# Can a getter return a thunk or value depending on the type call call (virt. property or function)?

Tags: javascript, getter, thunk

I know this a weird question, but I'll ask it anyway.

The pseudo code function below provides a virtual property getter. What it should do is this:

```
> const calc = Calculator(3)
> calc.multiple    // returns getter result directly
6
> calc.multiple(4) // returns thunk result, thus behaves like a function
12
```

Here's my pseudo code:

```
function Calculator(num) {

  return {
    get multiple() {
      if (isFunctionCalled()) {   // isFunctionCalled is an
                                  // imaginary function check
        return (mult = 3) => {
          return mult * num;
        };
      }
      // getter called, default calulation
      return 2 * num;
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to know from within `multiple` whether the value it returns, when used, will be used as a function or used as a non-function.

You could always return a function and provide the immediate value as a property on that function, but you can't return a number in one case but a function in another.

You can also play games with overriding the `[Symbol.toPrimitive]`, `valueOf`, and/or `toString` operations on the function you return, but that tends to produce surprising results when used in the wild.

You're probably best off differentiating by name, `multiple` vs. `getMultiple`, or `multiple` vs. `multipleThunk`, etc.